# Find largest intersecting diagonals

Tags: algorithm, matrix, diagonal

This is an interview question:

Given a n by m matrix of bits find the largest X that is formed in the matrix and return the size of the diagonal of that X. An X is defined as 2 equally sized diagonals that share a single 1.

For instance, the matrix:

```
00100001
00010010
00001100
00001100
00010010
00100001
```

Will return a size of 1, because the given X is invalid as the middle part does not share a single 1. On the other hand, the following matrix

```
101
010
101
```

Will return a value of 3, as the diagonal is 3. Write such program.

I understand the first solution discussed [here](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=6130581557477376), but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to solve this problem. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no asymptotic better solution with regards to time complexity. A weaker problem is to check if the matrix contains any 1-cell. For this problem you clearly you have to visit every cell, which gives you O(nxm). Now this is a lower bound to the original problem, which also has O(nxm). Qed.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand, at each (i, j) in the matrix, I will have to check top left, bottom right, top right, bottom left elements and there is no other way to improve the performance for this in anyway. Is that what youa re trying to suggest?

Comment: Yes and no: There is no better asymptotic solution. And yes, given a concrete algorithm to the solution in http://www.careercup.com/question?id=6130581557477376, you could tweak its performance by a constant factor. Which could be hard.